# Describing graphs with no induced path length $3$

Tags: graph-theory

I wanted to try and extend this earlier question: [Describe all graphs without a path of length 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272234/describe-all-graphs-without-a-path-of-length-3).

What if we know the graph has no *induced* paths of length 3? An induced path is an induced subgraph that is a path. I observed for example, that the complement of all graphs with no path length 3 was disconnected. Can we say something similar for all graphs with no induced path length 3?

Comment: Could you clarify your observation? Any edgeless graph is a graph with no path of length 3, yet its complement is connected.

Comment: Ah - perhaps it's better to say that either the graph is not connected or its complement is not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These graphs are called $P_4$-free graphs, and sometimes cographs, and are pretty well-known ($P_4$ is the induced path on $4$ vertices, i.e. the path of length $3$).

There are many characterisations, which I invite you to get acquainted with here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cograph

The one you mention is the following:

A graph $G$ is $P_4$-free if and only if for any induced subgraph $G'$ of $G$, 
either $G'$ or its complement is disconnected.

The fact that this is an "if and only if" makes it interesting.
There are other nice properties, see e.g. the cotree relationship with cographs.